# How to select everything using linq?

Tags: c#, json, linq

I'm creating some Services for my iOS application with JSON (I'm still a noob with that hole services story) My question:

Is it somehow possible to select everything using Linq like in SQL with a * ?

i got already the where clause so i put some effort in the hole story

```
   [DataContract]
    public class PublicVacationCalendarEntry
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }


    }
    [DataContract]
    public class PublicVacationCalenderEntryList
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<PublicVacationCalendarEntry> PVEntries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

im sry i posted the wrong code sry sry sry 
in this example i dont have something like a userId

Is it maybe something like that just some simple changes ?

Thanks for help and fast answer !

Comment: Return vd, a clone of vd, or overload the constructor for AnnualVacationCalendarEntry to take an argument of vd, or implement a converter. Can you rethink your variable names? vd from annalvacation just sounds wrong...

Comment: @Mingebag: You just **completely** changed your question! Don't do that. And now it doesn't make any sense anymore. Furthermore, you should be able to derive a solution from the answers posted here.

Comment: got it by myself with your help thx !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah, that's possible:

```
var annalVacation =  from vd in ctx.HtVacationDays
                     where vd.UserId == userId
                     select vd
```

or (the version I like even more)

```
var annalVacation =  ctx.HtVacationDays.Where(x => x.UserId == userId);
```

Comment: Why not `ctx.HtVacationDays.Where(x => x.UserId == userId)`? The query syntax provides no additional value. Quite the contrary, it is pretty verbose.

Answer (score 7):

You can write

```
from vd in ctx.HtVacationDays
where vd.UserId == userId
select vd
```

Because `vd` represents, if you will, one whole row from `HtVacationDays` you can just select it (by `select vd`), which will work just like `SELECT *`.

Also note, that you can use you lambda syntax (which you have mixed in with `.Where` clause in your code, like this:

```
var result = ctx.HtVacationDays.Where(x => x.UserId == userId); //Select is optional here.
```

Comment: @Mingebag - Now you have just a collection and no where clause anymore, furthermore, so I don't understand why you just did not return `PVEntries` in the first place. Is there something else that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

try if you need to automaticly convert one instance of a class to another try Automapper

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

```
        var annalVacation = ctx.HtVacationDays.Where(x => x.UserId == userId);
```